# Is it possible to set a personalized message to budget alerts on Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud

I want to set a budget alert to discharge a email when the bill reaches 80% of the budget. Is it possible to personalize the message that it will send by email?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes and No

No, you can do that with the native tools of google Cloud.

Yes, you can achieve that if you publish your budget alert in PubSub, and you plug a Cloud Functions/Cloud Run on that topic and generate your own email based on the message details. Don't forget to connected to a third party service, like sendgrid, to send email, there is no native service on Google Cloud to do that.